# Regular String to IDNA in Java

Tags: java, encoding, dns, web-standards

Is there a library that is able to parse Unicode domain name into IDNA? Like שלום.com ==> http://xn--9dbne9b.com/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java.net.IDN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/IDN.html) seems to do the trick. From my Scala console:

```
scala> java.net.IDN.toUnicode("xn--9dbne9b.com")
res0: java.lang.String = שלום.com
```

Note that it works on the hostname, not the URL. So you'll have to strip/extract the `http://` protocol first.

A quick glance at the documentation reveals it works in the opposite direction too. From above (my Unicode hostname in the variable `res0`)

```
scala> java.net.IDN.toASCII(res0)
res3: java.lang.String = xn--9dbne9b.com
```

Comment: java.net.IDN does only IDNA 2003. That is obsoleted by IDNA 2008 and has even security issues. The only Java API for IDNA 2008 I curretnly find is http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/IDNA.html

Comment: IDNA2008 in Java is requested here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6988055