# Encoded URL and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, http, encoding

I encode some URL parameters and URL becomes correct, but I still get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder makeUrlFromWord = new StringBuilder();

List<String> splittedUrl = mParser.splitRequest(urls[0]);

try {
    makeUrlFromWord.append("http://")
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(splittedUrl.get(0), HTTP.UTF_8))
        .append(".jpg.to/");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.d("Made url", makeUrlFromWord.toString());
```

Here is part of the log:

```
D/Made url﹕ http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82.jpg.to/
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
```

The link is correct, I tried this in browser, it decodes back in to Cyrillic symbols and works.

Comment: And which line threw the exception?

Comment: DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);
HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);  

last line

Comment: @RvdK its encoded one, has to work

Comment: `$ curl http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82.jpg.to/` gives `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82.jpg.to'`

Comment: In the browser I see `http://xn--b1agh1afp.jpg.to/` and `$ curl http://xn--b1agh1afp.jpg.to/` gives `                <img style="margin:0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" src="http://gifzona.ru/i/privet/01.gif" />
            `

Comment: So I suggest that you 1) try the `xn--` url and 2) read how that `%D0` is transformed into `xn--`

Comment: @18446744073709551615 how to encode to "xn--..."?

Comment: I meant you would search, find the answer, make your code work and then answer your own question on SO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936510/regular-string-to-idna-in-java

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/IDN.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the trick is to use [IDNA encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name):
Android defines [java.net.IDN](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/IDN.html) providing the conversion functions.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me. Converts "привет.jpg.to" to "http://xn--b1agh1afp.jpg.to/" thanks to @18446744073709551615

```
makeUrlFromWord.append("http://")
   .append(IDN.toASCII(splittedUrl.get(0)))
   .append(".jpg.to/");
```